# Problem Sync'ing/Downloading from Google Play

Tags: google-play-store

Android Enthusiasts

I've been having problems when trying to download apps from Google Play. I'm relatively new to the Android Scene. Whenever I try to download and install from Google Play, I get a (-101) error, telling me it couldn't be downloaded and installed. On a related note, since I can't get the apps to sync via wifi, I've been trying to sync via USB, which doesn't work well either. Doesn't even show up on my external devices. Is there anyone who can lend a hand?

Comment: Can you include the logcat **at** the point when downloading from google play?

Comment: logcat? Like I said, I'm new to the Android Scene, so I'm relatively ignorant on all the lingo. Resolved the -101 error on my own, though still need to figure out how to move files from my PC to the Tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> Settings>Apps>All>Google Play Store>Clear Cache & Clear Data
>
> Settings>Apps>All>Downloads>Clear Cache & Clear Data
>
> Settings>Apps>All>Download Manager>Clear Cache & Clear Data

If you're rooted I would suggest wiping cache & dalvik-cache from your recovery.
Also you could try installing the latest version of google play application using the apk.

Comment: I find the above to be a satisfactory resolution to almost every encounter with this problem I have had up to date. All I will add is briefly-if you are interested in this case you are probably going to be interested in the benefits of rooting the device even more. Best wishes, Your Genesis Bloke